# how to get text via backticks or system in Perl

Tags: perl, backticks

I want to call a EXE file in Perl which performs some action

I tried calling the exe file via `backtick` and `system` but in both the cases i get only the return value

The exe file prints some text on to the console. Is it possible to capture that as well?

I looked into this variable `${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}` but I get only  the return value and not text

I am using Perl 5.14

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application might not print its output to `STDOUT` but `STDERR` instead, which isn't captured by the backtick operator. To capture both, you could use the following:

```
my $binary = 'foo.exe';
my $output = `$binary 2>&1`;
```

For a more fine-tuned capturing, you might want to resort to [`IPC::Open3`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html) with which you can "control" all of a process' streams (`IN`, `OUT` and `ERR`).

Comment: Really? Then I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 1):

I used to execute commands from perl script and capture the output this way

```
sub execute_command() {
  my($host) = @_;
  open(COMMAND_IN, "your_command |"); 
  while (<COMMAND_IN>) 
  { #The COMMAND_IN will have the output of the command
    #Read the output of your command here...
    $ans = $_;
  }
  close(COMMAND_IN);
  return $ans;
}
```

Check whether it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the `capture` and `capture_err` functions from [Scriptalicious](http://search.cpan.org/~samv/Scriptalicious-1.16/lib/Scriptalicious.pod).

```
use Scriptalicious qw(capture);

my $output = capture('my_command', 'arg');
```

Comment: The module is four years old (`use 5.006`) and exports everything into the calling namespace (`@EXPORT`). There might be some issues (redefinition of `say` f.ex.) when using this module with more modern versions of perl.

Comment: Although it is old, the module works pretty well. You should probably imported the functions you need explicitly though. I added an example that does this.